# Recursive algorithm probability

Tags: probability, markov-chains, recursion, dice, recursive-algorithms

I'm trying to find the probability of obtaining a six on a dice roll following these rules:

> 1. You roll a dice and if you **roll $6$, then you win**.
> 2. However, if it is **not $6$, you roll another** dice.
> 3. If the number on that dice is **$3$ or less, then you repeat** steps 1, 2 and 3.
>    Otherwise (**$4$ or more**), you **lose**.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if, after the second step the number on the die is 4 or more? Do I win?

Comment: @ZaIra If the number is 4 or more, then you lose.

Answer (score 1):

Let the winning chance at the start be $p$.  Note that if you roll $1,2,3$ on step 3, you are back at the start, so the chance of winning when you invoke step 3 and roll $1,2,3$ is $p$ as well.  In step 3, do you lose on a $6$?  That is how I read the rules.  If so, your chance of winning at step 3 is $\frac 12p$.  You should get an equation in $p$ to solve.